# Return value of getSystemId()

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have a code in Java

```
    String xml = "/Users/test/xml/test.xml";
   // long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File(xml));
    System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is valid");
```

the XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE foo [ <!ELEMENT foo ANY >
<!ENTITY test SYSTEM "file:///Users/test/list" >]>
<cds>
   <user>&test;</user>
```

when i execute the code as per my understanding getSystemId should print "file:///Users/test/list" however it prints "/Users/test/xml/test.xml". Is there any error in my code or else is there any way to extract systemID?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is a bit away from what your code is doing.
The code is doing what it is supposed to do.

According to the documentation `StreamSource#getSystemId()` method returns:

> The system identifier that was set with setSystemId, or null if setSystemId was not called.

The output you get is correct because when you supply `new File(xml)` to `StreamSource` constructor, according to the `StreamSource` class definition it accepts as follows:

```
/**
 * Construct a StreamSource from a File.
 *
 * @param f Must a non-null File reference.
 */
public StreamSource(File f) {
    //convert file to appropriate URI, f.toURI().toASCIIString()
    //converts the URI to string as per rule specified in
    //RFC 2396,
    setSystemId(f.toURI().toASCIIString());
}
```

So, that's why you get the actual file name `/Users/test/xml/test.xml` you supplied, and not what your reasoning intends to.

I'm guessing you probably expected it would miraculously extract it from your `xml` file, in the line `<!ENTITY test SYSTEM "file:///Users/test/list" >]>`. This is wrong!

Try googling some xml parsing libraries, or parse the file contents yourself.

FYI:
- You can always look at the code of the classes you are using in your IDE.

ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html#getSystemId()